# Apt-get install show only last line

Tags: linux, bash, debian, apt-get

I'm making a post install script, to auto install some packages on linux machines. I want to show always the last line from the `apt-get install <package>` command. So the last line from `apt-get` have to rewrite the previous line.

So I imagine something like this:

```
----------------
Install Dev apps
----------------
[the last line from apt-get install here]
```

How can i do this in bash?

Comment: does `apt install blah | tail -n1` do the work? in the case of error though, don't you want to display more messages?

Comment: its works but i would like to see every line in the progress not just the end of the command.
So the last line from apt should rewrite the previous line

Comment: wow ok, that's not how your question means. you should probably reword it.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python script to do literally anything with the stdout and stderr of every command. As for your question, you can use the below script to see only the last line of the output:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess, sys
process = subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while process.poll() is None:
  stdout = process.stdout.readline().decode()[:-1]
  print(stdout,end='\r')
print()
```

Save the above code in a file such as *run.py*.
Then you can run any command to see only the last line of the output dynamically. For example:

```
./run.py sudo apt-get install <package>
```

or:

```
./run.py sudo apt-get update
```

> Note 1: Don't forget to give exec permission to your script:

```
chmod +x run.py
```

> Note 2: You can make a proper symlink for a more convenient usage (or alternatively add the script path to $PATH environment variable which I do not suggest):

```
sudo ln -s <path/to/yourscript.py> /usr/bin/run
```

Afterwards, you can only use:

```
run sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```